# Issue using events (as a function) v4

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Trying to import data from geojson by using [events (as a function)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function), but can't get anything to display. The lack of v4 examples for my specific case is making this difficult for me as well as the lack of errors. My code is below. The 'eventlist' is being correctly made based on my debug.log(eventlist) in the myevents function. For some reason my events don't display.

Any help would be great

```
<html lang='en'>

  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.2.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.2.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.2.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.2.0/main.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body><div id='calendar' class="mycal"></div></body>




    <script>

    function myevents()
    {
        var eventlist = [];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b5a1fce48210813dc66ccb6/5d2f8540e5892f506213cb11_Output.txt';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        window.eqfeed_callback = function(results)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++)
            {
                var obj = {};
                obj['title'] = results.features[i].properties.eventname;
                obj['start'] = results.features[i].properties.datestart;
                obj['end'] = results.features[i].properties.dateend;
                eventlist.push(obj);
            }
        }
        console.log(eventlist);
        return eventlist;
    }


      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid'],
            defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
            contentHeight: 'auto',
            header: { left: 'prev,next', center: '', right: 'title' },
            events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {   

                successCallback(myevents());

            }
        });

        calendar.render();

      });



    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you log the creation of each individual `obj` and note the order in which the logs appear in the console (particularly compared to when it logs the whole eventlist) you might start to see the problem - observe via this demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/pMEZNE . Also remember that browsers like Chrome can dynamically populate the log of an object retrospectively (in other words it can create the log entry, then add data to it later when the object is updated in the code), which isn't always helpful when you're trying to debug this kind of issue.

What I'm getting at is that you haven't taken into account the fact that your script file will be loaded **asynchronously**...

Luckily, since fullCalendar has already provided you with the `successCallback` to be called whenever you're ready to return the events, this is ideal for working with asynchronous scenarios. You can simply call the successCallback inside your asynchronous eq_feedbackCallback. This will ensure that you don't send the event list to fullCalendar before it's actually been populated.

```
function myevents(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src =
    "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b5a1fce48210813dc66ccb6/5d2f8540e5892f506213cb11_Output.txt";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

  window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
    var eventlist = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj["title"] = results.features[i].properties.eventname;
      obj["start"] = results.features[i].properties.datestart;
      obj["end"] = results.features[i].properties.dateend;
      eventlist.push(obj);
    }
    successCallback(eventlist);
  };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ["interaction", "dayGrid"],
    defaultView: "dayGridMonth",
    contentHeight: "auto",
    header: { left: "prev,next", center: "", right: "title" },
    events: myevents
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/gVwjzY